# OpenMP nested loop parallelization

Tags: for-loop, parallel-processing, nested, openmp

I am trying to parallelize two nested for loops using OpenMP. The problem I have encountered is that the serial execution time is way lower than the parallel execution time, something like 230ms/700ms. Also, the program doesn't work as intended once parallelized (results are wrong).

```
for(i=0; i<5000; i++)
for(j=0; i<5000; j++)
A[B[i][j]] = A[B[i][j]] + 1;
```

One of my attemps to parallelize it has been this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(guided) collapse(2)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are all the values of `B[i][j]` distinct from each-other? If not, you need to work a bit more for parallelizing this. Furthermore, how did you time your code?

Comment: `for(i=0; i<10; i++) A[i] = 0;` is the line just before these loops. Also, all elements in B are distict. The way I time my code is by using gettimeofday() at the beginning and at the end of these loops. Then, I print the difference.

Comment: This kind of indirect addressing doesn't play well with OpenMP (or similar approaches), it trashes any chances of benefiting from spatial locality of data.  And unless there are guarantees that all `B[i][j]` are different then there is a data race on some elements of `A` -- a canonical approach to writing incorrect parallel programs and one covered in multiple Qs and As under the OpenMP tag here on SO.

Comment: What are you timing? If you haven't executed a previous parallel region, you are including thread creation, which is expensive! (And, why don't you use omp_get_wtime()? It is an easier interface than gettimeofday())

Comment: The problem can't be on the way I time. I mean, my program gives me a wrong result by running it on parallel. Also, I want to include the time used by creating the threads, that's why I do it this way.